# "Variable and fixed" in categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology, topos-theory, notation

We often find in Grothendieck terminology the words variable and fixed (or absolute).

For example in [SGA 4](http://fabrice.orgogozo.perso.math.cnrs.fr/SGA4/index.html) studies variable topological spaces, groups, and categories as examples of morphisms of topos.

> I would like to know if there is a precise meaning of these two words in Grothendieck's terminology. Especially in the case of categories.

See for instance SGA 4 IV 4.6 "Le topos ̂  pour  catégorie variable."

Maybe this is related to the relative point of view.

Comment: I think the words are being used more or less in their ordinary, everyday meaning. For example, the section about "$\hat{C}$ for variable $C$" discusses the presheaf topos $\hat{C}$ and morphisms of presheaf toposes $\hat{C} \to \hat{C}'$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is really informal usage rather than formal usage.

By the way, the "relative" point of view can mean several things, for example:

- transforming a stagement say about algebras to a functorial statement in $\mathit{Alg}$.
- transforming a statement about a category to a slice category. For example, we can ask whether a Category is Cartesian Closed or whether all its slices are, in which case this is called locally Cartesian Closed.

Comment: Even if I find interesting the examples of relativity, the question asks for clarification of variable categories.